# Minimal LaTeX equation renderer on Windows (stripped MiKTeX?)

Tags: latex, equation, miktex

I'm successfully using MiKTeX to render LaTeX equation strings to PNG. However, the distribution of MiKTeX is really large (~360 MB for the uncompressed portable version), and I need only the equation rendering. Is there a stripped-down version of MiKTeX that eschews support for other features? Or is there stuff that I can remove safely and easily without breaking the equation rendering? (dictionaries, hyphenation stuff etc. comes to mind).

I'd really like to use MiKTeX or equivalent, since the quality of the output is critical. For example, I've messed around with JEuclid using MathML and the results were totally appalling in comparison. Of course, it may be that I did something wrong, but ...

Comment: Do you need LaTeX or can you get by with plain TeX?

Comment: Not sure actually. Is the syntax for specifically formulas any different? If plain TeX were an option, would that give me better possibilities in using a leaner distibution?

Comment: If you don't use fancy equations environments or fonts, then plain TeX surely can typeset all formulas. It just might not be too convenient for users that have LaTeX specific formulas. I'd start with the plain TeX version first. BTW, you may want to look at one of the several web service that exist for turning formulas into images. See for instance http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/ .

Comment: OK, I'll look into that. But can e.g. MiKTeX have its LaTeX bits stripped off, or is there a leander distribution with those properties? And regarding the web service tip, as I mentioned in another reply this is a batch renderer server that processes masses of documents that have LaTeX format equations in them, replacing them with images. So it's not a matter of making a few images myself, but rather installing a render server that will be making thousands of images over the coming years. :-)

Comment: if you're planning a server that will be up for years, you'd better invest into a state-of-the-art full TeX distribution, including LaTeX and much more.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only an equation renderer and you mind about installing big distributions, you can use some of the many web services provided on the internet. For example, at work, where I mind about installing big software ditributions, I normally use this php [**online equation editor**](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) which is pretty good.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, this is a batch renderer server that processes masses of documents that have LaTeX format equations in them, replacing them with images.